# Build Error with External Assembly in .NET6 Blazor Webassembly App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create Blazor Webassembly App with .Net6 using Visual Studio 2022(preview). And I've referenced external assembly file in that project. When I build the project, I got the following error,

> The asset 'D:\Office\Testing\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0\wwwroot_framework\ClassLibrary1.dll' can not be found at any of the searched locations 'D:\Office\Testing\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0\wwwroot_framework\ClassLibrary1.dll' and 'ClassLibrary1'

[screen shot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di9Eu.png)

Is there a solution for that ?

**Project's Properties here**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.0-rc.1.21452.15" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary1">
      <HintPath>Lib\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes></EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Include text in your question as text, not images.

Comment: The error is not in the posted code. Do post errors as text.

Comment: But 'Office' and `EmbedInteropTypes` hint at things not going to work in a Browser.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I edited the question.

Comment: The "as text" is just a general rule. The posted code looks OK-ish, the error really is elsewhere. Does the file get copied there? etc.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman. File should copy to output directory automatically, but it did not. I also changed "Copy Local" property of external assembly to "Copy Always", but it does not work.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, I'm seeing the same problem with RC2 and latest VS Preview

Comment: No I didn't @Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change this,

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="../Lib/ClassLibrary1">
     <HintPath>Lib\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
     <EmbedInteropTypes></EmbedInteropTypes>
   </Reference>   
</ItemGroup>
```